# Shared javascript library for Android tablet?

Tags: android, web-applications

Is there a shared JavaScript lib I can include into an Android webapp to provide native looking Android widgets?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Web Application frameworks which use JavaScript could be useful for you.

Check some of them.

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use PhoneGap (to transmit params form Native to JS use Phonegap.exec function).